# Company declines to share offer letter over email

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, india

I have a job offer from two companies, say A and B. Both the companies decline to share the offer letter over email. They are asking me to be at their office to get offer letter.

Is there any catch?

Is there a method or technique to persuade them to share the offer letter over mail?

Comment: Also, can you clarify if they are offering to give you the offer letter on the actual date of joining, or just want to be physically present to receive the offer letter?

Comment: What industry are you in?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Company A  promised me to offering offer letter  at the time of date of joining and company B asked me to physically present

Comment: @rath software industry

Comment: @vishalk is there a reason why you don't want to go in person? or why you need it to be via email?

Comment: Do you have all the information of both offer? Like salary, hours per weeks, holidays, training budget, etc.

Comment: Did you verbally accept any of these? Is there a deadline till you have to accept/reject these? Just drop by, pick up the letters, tell them you need to go over with your family (think about it) and make a decision after that.

Answer (score 6):

> Both the companies deny sharing offer letter over email. They are asking me to be at their office to get offer letter.

It's a commonly followed practise among mid-sized IT companies in India. It's apparent that neither of the companies want you to *shop around* using their offer letter for a better pay. In such cases, the candidate is typically handed the offer letter once they are present for completing the joining formalities.

Generally speaking, if they have denied sharing the offer letter email, there is no way you'll able to convince them otherwise (as should be apparent from the aforementioned thought process).

If you have a preference for one of the companies over the other, and have made up your mind to join them, seek a joining date and be available for completing the joining formalities.

Make sure to go through the job terms and conditions and the mentioned pay very carefully in your offer letter. Sign the letter only after you are convinced with the applicable terms and conditions.

Comment: Does it mean that you can't bring home the offer letter to read it carefully and, eventually, to compare it with the others taking your time to decide? That's insane.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Sad but yes!

Comment: Why is that "yes".
They don't want to email it because the privacy is put at risk. Why can't they mail it certified?

Comment: @RandyZeitman I am speaking from first hand experience dealing such sitations from the same locale.

Comment: Could OP forge an offer email for shopping around?

Comment: This is interesting. If it's a known practice in India not to give out the letter, why not just tell a company you have one pending but can't show it because they won't give it out? If they're gonna flex on pay, presumably they want you, so they'd hopefully believe you about having the other offer. Might be worth a shot to just tell them of the other offer.

Answer (score 2):

> Both the companies deny sharing offer letter over email. They are
>   asking me to be at their office to get offer letter. Is there any
>   catch? Is there any ways or techniques to ask them to share offer
>   letter over mail?

They've refused to send the offer letter by email.

Is there a catch? Yes, they want to present you the offer letter in person, as they've already told you.

Is there any ways or techniques to ask them to share offer letter over mail? You've already asked them to do that. They've already refused. So, no, I don't see how any "ways or techniques" could convince them otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO,
Your only option is to get both letters in person, say to both you want to think about it and come home to think it over

There may be subjective promises and "explanations" of particular offer details and options, but i wouldn`t rely on anything that is not in the letter itself